# Registry RegQueryValueExW

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder

Is it possible to read a value in the Registry not to an array of chars but directly to an AnsiString in this case?

```cpp
LONG result;
wchar_t buf[255] = {0};
DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(buf);
String d = "Nazwa";
DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;

result = ::RegQueryValueExW( hkSoftware, (LPCWSTR)(d.c_str()), NULL, &dwType, (LPBYTE)&buf, &dwBufSize );
```

Comment: I guess you would (at the very least) need to use the `RegQueryValueExA` (note the last letter) version. Trying to force a `wchar_t*` string into a `char*` string using a cast will generally end in tears. But I don't know, off-hand, how the C++Builder "String" class works, and whether you can write to its `c_str()` pointer.

Comment: ... or did you mean to use the `std::string` class? If so, writing directly to the pointer returned by that class `c_str()` member will also end in tears. Read your data into a `char[]` array then construct the `std::string` from that. Otherwise, you will have corrupt/meaningless control variables in that object.

Comment: Please look at this: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regqueryvalueexa) `If hKey specifies HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA and the lpData buffer is not large enough to contain all of the returned data, RegQueryValueEx returns ERROR_MORE_DATA and the value returned through the lpcbData parameter is undefined` and `You need to maintain a separate variable to keep track of the buffer size, because the value returned by lpcbData is unpredictable` How do I know what size of the array should I set?

Comment: @Jacek that same documentation tells you how, read it again more carefully: "*If hKey specifies HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA and the lpData buffer is not large enough to contain all of the returned data, RegQueryValueEx returns ERROR_MORE_DATA and the value returned through the lpcbData parameter is undefined. **This is because the size of the performance data can change from one call to the next. In this case, you must increase the buffer size and call RegQueryValueEx again passing the updated buffer size in the lpcbData parameter. Repeat this until the function succeeds.** ...*"

Comment: @Jacek in other words, start with a buffer size of your choosing. If it fails with `ERROR_MORE_DATA`, reallocate the buffer with a larger size and try again. Repeat until `ERROR_MORE_DATA` is no longer returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your code example is not using `AnsiString`. In C++Builder 2009 and later, `String` is an alias for `UnicodeString` instead.

And yes, you can use `UnicodeString` with `RegQueryValueExW()`, without using a typecast. [`UnicodeString::c_str()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString.c_str) returns a `WideChar*`, and `WideChar` is an alias for `wchar_t` on Windows, so `WideChar*` (aka `wchar_t *`) is implicitly convertible to `LPCWSTR` (aka `const wchar_t *`), eg:

```cpp
LONG result;
wchar_t buf[255] = {0};
DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(buf);
UnicodeString d = L"Nazwa";
DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;

result = ::RegQueryValueExW( hkSoftware, d.c_str(), NULL, &dwType, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&buf), &dwBufSize );
```

You can also use `UnicodeString` as a buffer to receive string data from `RegQueryValueExW()`, eg:

```cpp
LONG result;
UnicodeString buf;
buf.SetLength(...);
DWORD dwBufSize = ByteLength(buf);
UnicodeString d = L"Nazwa";
DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;

result = ::RegQueryValueExW( hkSoftware, d.c_str(), NULL, &dwType, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(buf.c_str()), &dwBufSize ); 
if ( result == 0 ) {
    buf.SetLength(dwBufSize/sizeof(WideChar));
    ...
}
```

That being said, you should consider using C++Builder's [`TRegistry`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry) class instead of using the Win32 Registry API directly. `TRegistry` has many methods for reading different kinds of data, including [`ReadString()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry.ReadString) for `String` data, eg:

```cpp
#include <Registry.hpp>

TRegistry *Reg = new TRegistry;
String buf;

Reg->RootKey = ...;
if (Reg->OpenKeyReadOnly(_D("...")))
{
    buf = Reg->ReadString(_D("Nazwa"));
    Reg->CloseKey();
}
delete Reg;
```